# Update material navigation drawer header

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I'm using the recently Google provided support library to add the navigation drawer to my app. In the navigation drawer's header, I define a CircleImageView to set user's profile pic, an his name under it.

[image]

All this info, is first defined by the user in the app's first start, so when the mainActivity starts, the image and the name are loaded into the header. But I'm giving the user the chance to modify these inside the app. If the user goes to the profile frag, and selects a new image as profile pic, or if he changes the name, this parameters won't update in the navigation drawer's header, until the app is closed and loaded again.

This is how I have it defined in mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

private NavigationView navView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ....

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                displayFragment(menuItem.getItemId());
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

There is no need to implement DrawerLayout.DrawerListener, but as seen in the top, I've done it to try to update the header in real time. These implements the next methods:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
}
@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        try {
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
            File directory = cw.getDir("profile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            File mypath = new File(directory, "thumbnail.png");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(mypath));
            thumbview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            username = mPreferences.getString("NAME", null);
            nameview.setText(username);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("LOAD_IMAGE", e.getMessage(), e);
            thumbview.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_thumbnail);
        }
}
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
}
@Override
public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
}
```

In the onDrawerOpened() method, I've used the same code I use in the onCreate to load the profile pic and the name. This should update these parameter every time the drawer is opened, but is not doing it, still does not update the header until I close and reopen the app.

Comment: what is the use of picExists?

Comment: @SAM it simply checks if there is a profile pic saved by the user. Is not relevant for the question so I have deleted

Comment: your profile might be not saved so check it by placing a `log` in `else` part. and you have provided the name `thumbnail.png` check whether you are saving it with same name?

Comment: @SAM it is being saved cause I see the updated pic and name in the frag for that purpose. Also if i close the app and reopen it, it updates the header. The method to update the header is the same I use in onCreate so it works fine. Here the problem seems to be with the method that has to indetify if the navigation drawer is being opened, and where to do those operations to update the header.

Comment: Can you show me the code where you applied the header ...?

Comment: @Moinkhan sorry but i don't understand what you mean, what code do you want to show?

Comment: Are you using new design support library-NavigationView?

Comment: @Harry Yes, I solved the way described in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In onCreate, I need to define the next code, to be able to update in real time the navigation drawer's header:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this);
        ...
```

Comment: How did you implement the while triangle? I tried a button and tried to make my ImageView clickable, couldn't even find the View, says null object.

Comment: The picture of the OP is just an example of what I wanted to achieve. I haven't implemented that white triangle. sorry but can't help